# Get Javascript 'type' for literal passed into a function

Tags: javascript, reflection

Given the following code:

```js
var testLiteral = {
  logMe: function() {
    logger(this, 'logMe message');
  }
}
console.log(Object.keys({ testLiteral })[0]);
logger(testLiteral, 'mainline message');
testLiteral.logMe();

function logger(caller, message) {
  console.log(Object.keys({ caller })[0] + ': ' + message);
}
```

We get these results:

- "testLiteral"
- "caller: mainline message"
- "caller: logMe message"

Is there any way to introspect the passed literal to see the original "object" name, i.e. `testLiteral`?  The results I'd be after would be:

- "testLiteral"
- "testLiteral: mainline message"
- "testLiteral: logMe message"

Note: `typeof` and `object.constructor.name` don't do the trick with literals, returning simply `object` and `Object` respectively.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to determine the variable name from the object. I don't think there will be a clean way to do that. You *could* give you object a `name` property and report that.

Comment: Definitely thought of that, but the thing I want to do is introspect things like node modules and library code written by other folks such that I can add better debug logging.  Basically I want it to work like Log4J and Log4Net

Comment: Sounds like a tough challenge. You might be able to get more info from class and function instances because they will have constructors with names and a prototype chain. But an object literal is just passed by value and doesn't care or know what variable(s) pointed to it. The library might save an object as `foo` and export it. You'll just get the object…but the `foo` name will be irrelevant by then.

Comment: Is calling a function on the initial `testLiteral` object permissible? eg, could you tolerate `var testLiteral = someFn({ logMe: function() { ...` where `someFn` resolves to the passed object?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var testLiteral = {
  logMe: function() {
    logger(this, 'logMe message');
  }

}
console.log(Object.keys({ testLiteral })[0]);
logger(testLiteral, 'mainline message');
testLiteral.logMe();

function logger(testLiteral, message) {
  console.log(Object.keys({testLiteral})[0] + ': ' + message);
}
```

Comment: So, sure, this gives the output I asked for, but it doesn't work generically.  The next class that implements `logMe()` would show as `testLiteral` versus it's own name.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap object before passing it to `logger` function. And for `testLiteral.logMe();` it will log `logMe` because `this` inside `logMe` function will refer to itself.

```js
var testLiteral = {
  logMe: function() {
    logger(this, 'logMe message');
  }
}
console.log(Object.keys({ testLiteral })[0]);
logger({ testLiteral }, 'mainline message');
testLiteral.logMe();

function logger(caller, message) {
  console.log(Object.keys(caller)[0] + ': ' + message);
}
```

Comment: So this is close, but can we get to the actual parent object of `logMe()` versus the function itself?

Comment: No. It will not be possible in case of literal. As Mark Meyer has also explained same in his comment that it could be possible with class and function but with literal there is no hope.